# Momentum and indirect bandgap

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When an electron is excited from valence band to conduction band, it has to have a finite momentum in the case of indirect bandgap. Does that mean that the electron cannot be created at rest ? does it have a non zero "speed" ?

Answer (score 1):

It means that to fulfill momentum conservation law, the momentum should be taken from somewhere: from phonons, impurities, etc.

The speed is a derivative of the energy (remember Hamilton's equations), thus the speed is zero at the minimum of the energy, wherever this point is located in **k** space

Comment: I am not familiar with Hamilton's formulations. Does that mean that momentum is not equal to mass*speed for electrons in a solid ?

Comment: In general case [$v\equiv\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_equations#Simplified_overview_of_uses) which leads to $\dot{q}=p/m$ only if $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+U(q)$